# Using Counters breaks the allignment of first entry in tabular environment. How do I fix this?

Tags: tables, counters

I'm wanted to use automatic numberation of rows in the tabular environment, but the counter seems to break the allignment of the first entry in that column.

Here is a minimal working example

```
\newcounter{AFList}
\stepcounter{AFList}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \textbf{Nr.} & \textbf{Thing} & \textbf{Value}\\

    \theAFList & first & $0,5 - 2\,mm$\\ \stepcounter{AFList}
    \theAFList & second & $0,5 - 2\,mm$\\ \stepcounter{AFList}
    \theAFList & third & $0,5 - 2\,mm$\\ \stepcounter{AFList}
\end{tabular}
```

which produces this:

[image]

I would like all the numbers to be alligned. Thanks for any help.

Cheers.

Comment: you could use `\stepcounter{AFList}%`  so you do not add the space after the assignment

Comment: unrelated but `mm` should be `\mbox{mm}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you that fixed the problem. Turn out only the first row was correctly alligned and now they all are ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a "%" after each "\stepcounter{AFList}" like David Carlisle proposed in his comment worked for me:

"you could use `\stepcounter{AFList}%` so you do not add the space after the assignment" – David Carlisle

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your code. I also add `siunitx` to format ranges of measures; note that repeating the unit is good practice so the reader doesn't mistake the dash for a minus sign.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,},range-phrase={--}}

\newcounter{AFList}
\newcommand{\AFL}{\stepcounter{AFList}\theAFList}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{Nr.} & \textbf{Thing} & \textbf{Value}\\
\AFL & first  & \SIrange{0,5}{2}{mm} \\
\AFL & second & \SIrange{0,5}{2}{mm} \\
\AFL & third  & \SIrange{0,5}{2}{mm} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats a good Idea, thanks ;)